# I have requests but not impressions in admob

Tags: admob, interstitial

I have 49 request in an interstitial ad but 0 impression. I only need to wait to will have impressions?
And other question:
Why fill rate is 100%. I think that should be 0%. Isn't it?

MyActivity:

```js
package com.ais3.speedconverter;



import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;



public class Main2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3741254829134290/3336434152");


        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);

    }


    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

   


}
```

My androidmanifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.Myapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icona"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"  >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

The admob banner work well done but the interstitial no.

Comment: Did you try yourself to get an interstitial ad? did you ever see one live in your app? (and yeah it should be 0%, those metrics are sometimes very weird)

Comment: Yes I did. But I've never have seen an interstitial in my app. I suppose that I haven't got enough impression to can see it. Can it be?

Comment: did you ever see an test interstitial? post some code! Could be something wrong there!

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question:

> Why fill rate is 100%? I think that should be 0%.

Interstitial ads use delayed impression counting. If you never show the interstitial, an impression is not recorded. But you did receive the ad, so it counts positively towards your fill rate.